# fail2ban configure third-party email server

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid, host, fail2ban

I'm using fail2ban on Google Compute Engine where I can't install sendmail or other email servers and I would to set sendgrid as email server.

In jail.local there is this config:

```
destemail = myemail@myhost.it
mta = mail
```

Where can I set the host, user, password to send emails via sendgrid.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `fail2ban` uses the machine `mail` command to send email, thus it is using the machine mailing daemon. If you look at this snippet:

```
# Option:  actionstart
# Notes.:  command executed once at the start of Fail2Ban.
# Values:  CMD
#
actionstart = printf %%b "Hi,\n
              The jail <name> has been started successfully.\n
              Regards,\n
              Fail2Ban"|mail -s "[Fail2Ban] <name>: started  on <fq-hostname>" <dest>
```

that is taken from [here (`fail2ban` sources on github)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/b5dd5adb08f9fd3496f8c63b1d53b0e3c6aabbf1/config/action.d/mail.conf#L16), you can see that a message of `fail2ban` is piped to the `mail` command (in Debian based distribution this is installed via the `mailutils` package). Since I think your problem is that **you cannot use or configure this `mail` command** (which means configuring the mail server), you may think to write a very simple `mail` binary (in the language you prefer), with a pretty similar interface that may use something like the Gmail App Script to send the email, or even Gunmail or Sendgrid to actually send an email from that machine (with a POST request through the REST Api? Do they allow you?), and add this custom binary to the `$PATH` of the user that runs `fail2ban`.

---

**Edit**: There is a [page in the Google compute documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) related to Send Grid. Also according [to this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) **you cannot** use sendmail: the ports are closed.

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to. In addition, having a trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with your receivers.

Comment: I think I have to do something like this:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/sendmail.html
Configuring sendmail to use sendgrid

Comment: Check the answer again, I think I found a solution in Google documentation.